# Meaning of 焦りが見えることを見透かしていた

Tags: meaning

In context, the character, who currently coaches for his school’s team, was called out by his 先生 as she could tell he was 焦っている.

他校の練習の充実ぶりに圧倒され、なかなか先に進まない練習と、何よりも自分に。

**焦りが見えることを、先生は見透かしていた**。

A quick google turned up another similar usage (or what I think is similar) on this [page](https://auracolor.com.tw/blog/007-%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B8%E3%83%8E%E3%83%AD%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A4%E3%83%AB-%E3%83%8D%E3%82%BF%E3%83%90%E3%83%AC-%E8%A7%A3%E8%AA%AC-afd58b) about Casino Royale (James Bond):

ゲームをプレイするボンドは、シッフルに焦りが見えることを見抜き

However, what is confusing me is that I understood 見透かす/見抜き to be used to "see through" something i.e. to see through the surface level. I understand 焦りが見える to mean something like 焦り is visible / can be seen. Clearly "seeing through" something which is visible doesn't make any sense to me so I'm obviously misunderstanding something somewhere.

If this was literally what it was saying, then what would have been the difference in meaning if he had said something like:

俺が焦っているのを、先生は見透かしていた